# Unable to use system restore (0x080070026)

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

Main part of the issue is self-explanatory, but there is a lot to add in for where this came from.
Originally I was doing this because I (accidentally) Updated the Realtek audio drivers and it made many things worse - mic quality was awful (constant buzz) and audio quality is worse on the headset.

I tried using system restore, which on its initial use gave me the error 0x8007045b.

**What i have tried doing:**

First thing I found was a website that basically linked this error to a mistake in windows that closed a service, then wanted to use it so caused an error. the fix for this was meant to be to run system restore in WinRE.

I then found that it didn't exist on my PC, so I found an article for pulling it out of an image file downloaded through the media creation tool, and then after that ran system restore, which then gives this error instead.

Another thing to note is that i have tried two separate restore points and both bring up the same error.

Also I have used SFC and DISM for error checking and repairing errors.

[image]

Comment: While this is indeed a duplicate, I would skip trying to "backup" WindowsApps, since the directory will have the incorrect permissions if you do that.  You will have to download your UWP applications again but in most cases they are extremely small.  If the duplicate's answer does not resolve the problem, you will have to provide explicit details, as your current explanation is extremely vague.

Comment: Unfortunately i believe that solution won't work. While i did forget to add it in the answer, when i tried to remane it in winRE it said the folder doesn't exist, so as far as I know that cannot solve it.

Comment: The file most certainly exist.  It has to exist.  The folder is the reason you failed to recovery the recovery point.  You do understand the full path to that directory is C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ right?